# How can I import a csv with unknown dimension?

Tags: matlab

I have a csv file which I want to imported as one cell array of strings. The problem is that the number of rows and columns can vary. How can i write a script which allow the import regardsless of the csv dimension?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using [csvread](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/csvread.html) you do not need to specify the amount of rows and columns, though it is an option.

Comment: I guess csvread only works for numeric values. I have mixed entries (numeric and strings)

Comment: In that case use `xlsread`. Most of the time I end up needing specifically raw data, so `[num,txt,raw] = xlsread('myfile')` or `[~,~,raw] = xlsread('myfile')` if you only need the data. Read about it in the Mathworks docs.